# Why is no exception thrown when dismissing a ProgressDialog from a background thread?

Tags: android

I know that when I try to show ProgressDialog on background thread following exception is thrown `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`,

because we are trying to modify UI from background thread. But when we dismiss that dialog in background thread no exception is thrown. Why no exception is thrown when we dismiss dialog in background thread as by dismissing we are also modifyng UI from background thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code for Dialog's dismiss() method, showing why no exception is thrown and the dismiss works:

```
/**
 * Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be
 * invoked safely from any thread.  Note that you should not override this
 * method to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement
 * that in {@link #onStop}.
 */
public void dismiss() {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
    } else {
        mDismissAction.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the implementation of the .dismiss() method from the Dialog class as it is in 2.2:

```
 public void dismiss() {
         if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
             mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
         } else {
             mDismissAction.run();
         }
     }
```

As you can see, it checks if you're trying to call it from the UI thread. If you do, it'll just dismiss itself. But if you're dismissing it from another thread, it handles this action through a Handler, which was created on the UI thread, hence it will process the dismiss action on the UI thread.